# Particle Info Node and Blender Internal Render

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

What user errors are in the Blender Internal Render Nodes below?

RC 2.76 with Particle Info Node.

[image]

[image]

The render result is not what the user intended.

[image]

version 2.76 (sub 0), branch b'master', commit date b'2015-09-23' b'14:02', hash b'e24ea81', b''
build date: b'Thu 09/24/2015', b'09:51 AM'
platform: b'Windows'

Comment: Blendfile will probably help.

Comment: I can reproduce this, consider making a blend and submitting as a bug. An identical setup for Cycles does not have this problem.